# Returning ResultSet without close?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I would like to have a database connection managing class which I can use for simple `SQL` commands like `SELECT`, `INSERT` etc. by simple calling something like this (class below):

```
ResultSet test = DataService.getResultSet("SELECT NOW()");
test.first();
System.out.println(test.getString(1));
```

This is class I've found on web:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Database object to load drivers and perform queries
 * @author Abdulsalam Umar blog.salamtura.com
 */
public class DataService {

    private static Connection con;
    private static final String Driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String ConnectionString = "Your database connection string";
    private static final String user = "username";
    private static final String pwd = "password";

    /**
     * create Database object
     */
    public DataService() {
    }

    /**
     * to load the database base driver
     * @return a database connection
     * @throws SQLException throws an exception if an error occurs
     */
    public static Connection loadDriver() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(Driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString, user, pwd);
        return con;
    }

    /**
     * to get a result set of a query
     * @param query custom query
     * @return a result set of custom query
     * @throws SQLException throws an exception if an error occurs
     */
    public static ResultSet getResultSet(String query) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = loadDriver();
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        return rs;
    }

    /**
     * to run an update query such as update, delete
     * @param query custom query
     * @throws SQLException throws an exception if an error occurs
     */
    public static void runQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = loadDriver();
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
        st.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Is this way of returning `ResultSet` without closing it (and closing the statement) right? How can I return the `ResultSet` from the method?

Comment: Or another example: http://www.programcreek.com/2009/06/prototype-of-database-class/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a ResultSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853508/returning-a-resultset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning result set is not a good idea. So,fetch the required data and make use of collection to return the data.
[This answer may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853625/2830834)

Answer (score 0):

How about passing a callback that takes `ResultSet` as parameter and let client code do whatever needs to inside it while you make sure that everything is cleaned up afterwards.

This is pattern in used in spring JDBC `ResultSetExtractor` and `RowMapper`. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793165/spring-resultsetextractor).

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `ResultSet` because it will be closed when method destroyed. But you can get raw data from `ResultSet`, try this:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<byte[]>> getResultQuery(String query){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<byte[]>> tableResult = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<byte[]> row;
    conn = getConnection(db_url);
    try {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        int countColumn = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        if (countColumn==0) return null;
        while (resultSet.next()){
            row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i<countColumn; i++){
                row.add(i,resultSet.getBytes(i+1));
            }
            tableResult.add(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tableResult;
}

public static Connection getConnection (String db_url){
    Connection conn = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

In this, i try to return `ArrayList` of `ArrayList<byte[]>`, `ArrayList<byte[]> = 1 row` in `ResultSet`. If you want to get some value, just use `row.get(i)` to get value from `column i+1` in `ResultSet` which look like a 2 dimensions Matrix